# What is the default Lock Screen Wallpaper?

Tags: lumia, lock-screen

An app changed the wallpaper on my lock screen. I was so mad at the app, I uninstalled it.

I'd like to go back to the default wallpaper, but I don't remember what the default wallpaper was.

If it makes a difference, my phone is a Nokia Lumia 710.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the wallpaper (back), you simply go to Settings > lock+wallpaper, and choose the <kbd>change wallpaper</kbd> button.

The default wallpapers will show in a folder called "Wallpapers" (which won't show via the Pictures Hub). These will include a mix of any operator customised wallpapers, any manufacturer customised wallpapers and those from Microsoft. On my HTC device, this is a set of 40 to choose from.

The wallpaper on my device *was* the forth up from the bottom, on the right; but on my wife's, hers was the third down on the left. Another device of the same make/model I have access to used the third up on the left. Given this, I'm led to believe that there is no single default, but one is selected at random at some point during setup.

Comment: I think you're right Rowland. It is probably a random selection, since mine was different from your two. You got me to look through all of them and I found the one that was mine: 8th down on the left - blue-greenish looks like unfocused water droplets. Windows Phones are meant to be personalized, so I suppose the randomization of the default is designed to help you make your phone yours.

Answer (score 0):

The default wallpaper on your phone can be set by nokia or your carrier/network so it is probably different for most people.

There should be a wallpapers folder in your photos hub so it will be one of those.

I also don't think an app can change a user's wallpaper but that's not a different story...

Comment: I think the app did change it, because the wallpaper became a screen shot of one of the screens from the app.

Comment: It could be random, as Rowland thinks, or you might be right. But Rowland had two different phones (probably with the same carrier) with different default wallpapers.

Answer (score 0):

Default Lock Screen Wallpaper is one of the Sample Images provided by Microsoft in the pictures hub. Select one and change it. I know this because last week I had reset my phone. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes, but which one was the default? That is what I forgot and want to know.

Answer (score 0):

The default wallpaper on lumia 710 is a man like character made of sticks. You can find the same in *Pictures•Albums•wallpaper*

Comment: That is your phone's default. But that wasn't my default.

Comment: Just one option to know it then. Reset your phone. Or go to a nearby store and see the default wallpaper on new device

Comment: I have no desire to reset my phone and lose who-knows-what I've already set up on it. But your seconds suggestion - to go to a store and see the default - is a good one.